# Can't change language (only "English (United States)")

Tags: wp-admin, language

Wordpress should always allow me to change the language, anytime. However, sometimes I get stuck in these kind of situations, where I only get to choose "English (United States)".

*(Settings > General Settings > Site Language)*

### What I expect:

[image: a]

### What I get:

[image: a]

Why is that? How can I fix this?

Comment: So... nobody knows?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: This might be a permissions issue—does Wordpress have the correct permissions?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. When I am trying to change the language it is only the showing one language i.e English other languages are not showing in the drop down Please suggest or tell me if anyone has the solution for the same. So I can fix the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141911)

Comment: Late response but I had the same issue *(during an installation)* and what was the reason here... *(my bad)* not the full permission given to that specific virtal domain. So my solution was as mentioned by @Stuart already, setting correct permissions. *(e.g. for Centos 7 `chown -R apache:apache /path/to/virtual/domain` and SELinux giving the correct settings)* That allowed me after installation to select another language.

Comment: Check out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189554/what-security-concerns-should-i-have-when-setting-fs-method-to-direct-in-wp-co for a more detailed explanation of what is going on here.

Answer (score 26):

Maybe WordPress doesn't have permissions to save the new language files. I had the same problem, and I solved it by adding the following to `wp-config.php`

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

You might also want to check that your `wp-content/`-directory is writable for the web server user.

Comment: That should be accepted answer, the other ones are workarounds.

Comment: Dawid: FS_METHOD has nothing to do with the language per se, but it's nice that it solved your problems. The other answers are according to what the WP team writes here (so not really a workaround, just manual install): https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language#Manually_Installing_Language_Files

Comment: Change `wp-content` permission to 777 solved the issue!

Comment: @John_J re:777: To test if permissions are the problem ok, but don't use 777 in a production environment, recommended permissions for folders 755 - see WordPress Codex 'Changing File Permissions' 'The dangers of 777'

Comment: It was a permission problem for me (Ubuntu). Fix: `~$ chown -R www-data /path/to/wordpress`

Comment: i have all in www-data, and by chown www-data again just like what @SeuMadruga said, it fix.

Answer (score 13):

I have no experience with WP before. I tried to install WP 4.7 and have same problem. Only English was in dropdown list.
I thought WP downloads all translate files automaticall but unfortunately it didn't.

To get languages in dropdown list (Settings > General Settings > Site Language)
you need install translate files to `wp-content/languages` directory.

To download language file select version of WP here
https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp
than select language.
You will get a page where you can download language file.

For example for wp4.7 Ukraine I have got this page

```
translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/4.7.x/uk/default
```

At the end of the page find `Export` link.
Select **'all current**' as '**Machine Object Messages Catalog (.mo)**'
and click `export`

Then put downloaded file in **wp-content/languages** directory.
Open or refresh  Settings > General Settings page.
You should see new language in dropdown list.

It is **important to download .mo file** exactly. I spent a lot of time trying to install .po file.
Also if you linux user and have only .po file you can convert it by command

```
msgfmt -o uk_UA.mo uk_UA.po
```

To install translate files for plugins and themes you should to do same things with some difference.

More details you can find here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

Comment: This works for me perfectly. thank you.

Comment: Thanks, still applies in 2024.

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into the same issue. In my case, the reason was simple. When you install an English-only version of WordPress, there is no `languages` subdirectory under the `wp-content` directory. Create it manually, and you will receive all available language list at your WP dashboard.

### 1. Create the target directory

By default, the "content" directory is `<wordpress folder>/wp-content`. However depending on your installation it might not be that one.

To check, run `wp eval "echo WP_CONTENT_DIR;"`

Once you have identified that directory, create a `languages` directory in it.

### 2. Install languages

If Wordpress doesn't have permissions to install languages for you into that folder, you can do it yourself by placing the `.po` and `.mo` files in it. Restart Wordpress and it will pick them up.

### 3. Install languages for plugins and themes

#### 3.1 First option: Let Wordpress download them

At this point, you got WP core translation files, but not the plugins or themes ones. To get all other translation files, go to **Updates** section under **Dashboard**, and click **Check again** button. At the bottom of the page you'll see a message *New translations available*. Click on the **Update translations** button, and WP will download all available translations for your plugins and themes.

#### 3.2 Second option: place them yourself manually

As mentioned above, Wordpress must have write permissions on `languages` directory, in other case you'll have to download all translation files manually. Place `.po` and `.mo` translation files for installed themes in `languages/themes` subdirectory, and translation files for installed plugins in `languages/plugins` subdirectory.

Comment: I had to add `languages` and add a .mo file as described in another answer. This is useful.

Comment: At the bottom of the relevant WP translation team page, be sure to select "Machine Object Message Catalog" and click "Export". Name it something nice and copy the .mo file to the languages folder.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is occurred in WordPress 4.0 and above versions also , because of permissions. Because of this WordPress cannot download the language packs. To add other languages in admin panel general settings , add this code inside **wp-config.php** just below the **define('WP_DEBUG', true);**

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

After saving changes check on admin panel general settings , now you will find number of languages. And if in case you will not find your language inside a list , try to add a language packs using plugin or add through code. You can follow official documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. 
In case you have a multi-language plugin installed, you have to deactivate it(or delete it) and then you will be able to change the language to whatever you need. I had this problem specifically with Multisite Language Switcher.

PS. i checked before and i had the language files in my wordpress installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I spent hours to read different complicated solutions.

**Just 3 very basic steps.**

**1** Create a new folder in your ‘/wp-content’ directory called ‘/languages’
**2** Copy in this folder the language pack of the language you want to install
   (download it from https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/)
**3** Choose the new language through the interface

Details here: https://www.linuwi.com/tutorials/how-to-change-wordpress-language/

Answer (score 1):

Like Ivan described above, make sure PHP has the right file permissions so it can create a /languages subdirectory under the /wp-content directory. If it has, it will create the directory automatically and let you select a language unter Settings > General Settings > Site Language.

Answer (score 1):

In my case since I was using **WPML** for translation, I had to go to the WPML Setup Page, to change my default language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue defining the right way wordpress search for the `wp-content` folder.

In `wp-config.php` you can specify the position of the `wp-content` folder. Based on the system you are working on, try to set the following code:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content'));
```

or this one:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content'));
```

Comment: I tried both. Neither worked.